# Fastest way to remove fraction value of a number in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I know there are many ways to remove the fractional value of a number.

For example, if I have a variable with the type of `double` and the number: `12.34`.
And want to convert it to an `int`, this is what I can do:

```
int var = (int)fractionalVar;
int var = (int)Math.Round(fractionalVar);
int var = (int)Math.Truncate(fractionalVar);
```

So my question:
Which one is the fastest or is there a faster one?

EDIT: My fault, I don't mean to round anything. This is what I mean:
Remove the fractional value from the number.
Example. 12.34 to 12 AND ALSO 12.99 to 12.

Comment: [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Benchmark it and see...in a real-world application

Comment: But Math.Round will not give you the same result as the other two, which makes me wonder is this an actual problem.. `Convert.ToInt32` would not need a cast as well as Rounding/Truncating.

Comment: First one - because it uses less operations. (it's not a suggestion to use it, it's just a fact.). First one only casts, others calculates and casts.

Comment: Why are you worried about speed on something like this?  Any differences would be so small that they wouldn't matter.  What is your real problem?

Comment: Be careful.  Round and Truncate will give different results depending on if the number has a decimal greater than 0.5.  By the statement "remove the fractional value" I would interpret this as Truncate or (int)fractionalVar, but not Math.Round.

Comment: @Adriani6 [Convert.ToInt32](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,1087) is equivalent to `Round()` implemented as a cast and possible increment

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Exactly.. My point in the comment was that the 2nd example doesn't do the same thing as the other two on the list.. and explain about possible increment if `Round()` does that? I'm a little confused by your last two words.

Comment: I am sorry I did an error there, I meant to simply remove the fractional number not round it. So what I mean is: from 12.34 to do 12. Or from 12.99 to do 12.
I am going to edit this.,

Comment: @MaratIsaw You can see a sample benchmark [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KW7EW4). It's not entirely accurate because of the cloud environment however it's clear enough to provide a basic idea.

Comment: @Adriani6 Thanks, but I formed my question not right. I meant just to remove the fractional value. Anyway thanks for your effort to help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all three methods cast a double, the two that call functions will be slower since there is more work to do. This can be confirmed with a benchmark.

```
          Method |      N |      Mean |     Error |    StdDev |
---------------- |------- |----------:|----------:|----------:|
    BasicIntCast | 100000 | 0.0001 ns | 0.0002 ns | 0.0002 ns |
    RoundAndCast | 100000 | 0.0514 ns | 0.0064 ns | 0.0056 ns |
 TruncateAndCast | 100000 | 5.4704 ns | 0.0197 ns | 0.0165 ns |
```

As others have mentioned, your desired end result should determine which method you use. If you really want e.g. 12.999999... to become 12, then the cast to int will get the job done.

EDIT: Also be careful of overflowing on the cast!

```
        double d = 12e25;
        int i = (int)d;
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        // -2147483648
```

Comment: Ok, if that is really the best way to remove the fractional value. Then I got what I need. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

Disregarding the "fastest" question - use `Math.Truncate`. Why? Because your question is basically "which is the fastest way to truncate." That's irrelevant. They are all very fast and `O(1)`. Use the cleanest one. The one that's called like the action you actually want to perform.

Also read this:
https://blog.codinghorror.com/micro-optimization-and-meatballs/

On a side-note `Round` has different behavior from `Truncate`.

Comment: Though all are perhaps all O(1) I suspect all three methods result in different IL and therefore different computational time

Comment: I have edited my answer, thanks for your effort anyway :)

Comment: Citing the msdn documentation:
"`Math.Truncate`Calculates the integral part of a number."